# Keycloak server configuration: Path Permission For Only One Role/Group

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm having some problems to configure a keycloak server. I created two roles, two groups (one per role) and two users (one in each group). Now I'm trying to give the authorization to access to a specific path (e.g http://localhost:8080/api/private/premium) only to one of my groups.

I created (under Authorization tab) a resource with the URI that I want to protect, a policy (type group) and a permission. I also use the Evaluate tab to test this configuration and I get the correct result: result DENY for the user in the group NOT associated with the policy, result PERMIT for the user in the other group. 
 So I tried to test the configuration using POSTMAN:

1_ get the access tokens of my two users (http://localhost:7070/auth/realms/REST_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token).

2_ get the protected resource (http://localhost:8080/api/private/premium), first with the unauthorized user, then with the authorized.

The problem is that I get the resource correctly in both cases (I was expecting an error message for the call with the authentication token of the unauthorized user).
Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you give some more details on your implementation like programming language, used framework, details of your backend Keycloak config, ...

Comment: Programming language is not important because in this moment I'm doing tests only with postman.

Comment: I'm trying to insert in this question the json of the keycloak server configuration, but I can't because it exceeds the max number of rows for a question

Comment: It is somewhat important as there are differences in enabling the policy enforcer. Checkout the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_filter) and paste the content of your `keycloak.json` (client config).

Comment: Ok you can find the configuration file of the server here: https://github.com/AndreaSala013/config